# Turn off Touchswipe on Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

Building a site where each swipe makes the site transition between full-screen-sized divs. The actual framework is built to have each full-sized divs take up the full viewport with no overflow.  THis is the nature of the framework.  However, I have an interior div that has overflow content that can be scrolled.  However, when the site detects a touchswipe up or down, it transitions to the next screen, versus letting you scroll on the overflow div.

Is there a way to turn off touchswipe on a certain div and allow normal scrolling action?

Can provide code example if needed

Comment: always include example code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using [Ramp Interactive's TouchSwipe](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/), it looks like you can just add an event handler to your scrolling `div` to [stop propagation](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Stop_propegation.html) of the `swipe` event:

```
$(function() {      
    $("#yourdiv").swipe( {
        swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, fingerCount) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit:**

Actually, it [looks like](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Excluded_children.html) you can just add the `.noswipe` class to your `div` instead.